# how to re-use a .bind from a js file in my code? 

Tags: javascript, jquery, merge

Edit: changed the question and title a bit to make things more clear

Hi there,

I have a php file, where in I call the jquery script and a big javescript file. In the php file itself I use the following script:

```
<script>
<!-- Hide/show divs using fadein/out --> 
$("#game_board_container").click(function(e){
    $('#status2').html('+'+ 100);
    $("#status2")
    .hide()
    .css({
      top: e.pageY -20,
      left: e.pageX -10,
        opacity: 1,
        marginTop: 0
     })
        .show()
        .stop()
        .delay(200)  
       .animate({'marginTop':-75, opacity: 0},1000);
    });
</script>
```

This script shows a hidden div (status2) at the mouse position when clicked in div "game_board_container". This works great. The problem is, this happens when I click the mouse, which I don't want. I want this to happen not on click, but on an event called: found_match. A solution would be to bind this to the event.

This bind already exists. In the big js file there is the following code line:

```
$(document).bind("found_match", foundMatchingBlocks);
```

So how can I use this .bind to replace my .click?

Many thanks

Comment: I didn't quite get it. If the matching of the squares is checked on click event why don't you want the whole thing done onclick?

Comment: How is the foundMatchingBlocks function being called? Is it attached to some event handler already?

Comment: changed the question to make thing more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery custom event capability. Use `$("#special").bind('eventName', fn)` to attach event on element and raise event from `foundMatchingBlocks` using  `$("#special").trigger('eventName')`. Learn more http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I've found this part of code in the big js file: `$(document).bind("found_match", foundMatchingBlocks);` so I gues I can use this to replace the .click, but again how to do this? Tried `$("#special").bind("found_match", foundMatchingBlocks, function(e){`, no succes

Comment: on any user action (let's say click) call findMatchingBlocks and when it find something call $("#special").trigger('eventName')